# check_box_tag :called and check status error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im trying to use the :called method on a check_box_tag and of also remembering the state of the boolean which comes from the DB.

If I set the check_box_tag without the checked param, it shows and saves the check into the db with the called method, but I cannot use both checked and called on the same check_box_tag

heres the code

**EDIT**
I changed from form for to form_tag by Hugo Logmans suggestion:

```
<%= form_tag(courses_pensum_path(course_pensum.id), method: :put, remote: true, id: "edit_courses_pensum_#{course_pensum.id}") do %>
              <%= hidden_field_tag(:pensum_id, value=current_pensum.id) %>
              <%= hidden_field_tag(:course_id, value=course.id) %>
              <div class="form-inline">
                <%= check_box_tag name="type[]", value="other_area", checked: (course_pensum.other_area ? true : false),
                    :called, :onclick => "$('#edit_courses_pensum_#{course_pensum.id}').submit()" %>
                <%= label_tag 'OA', nil, class: "checkbox" %>
              </div>
            <% end %>
```

as it is it shows an argument error for check_box_tag, I guess its a dumb problem but then I have not seen it..

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Why are you mixing a form_for with those non-form_form tags? Use f.check_box :called, :onclick =>"yourhandler".

Comment: I get a nomethod error called for f.check_box :called :onclick +> xx, the form is for a join table with has_many through... dont know if thats whats affecting it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I thought it was a syntax error that a friend here helped me to figure out...

This is what I ended up with in the form

```
<%= form_tag(courses_pensum_path(course_pensum.id), method: :put, remote: true, id: "edit_courses_pensum_#{course_pensum.id}") do %>
              <%= hidden_field_tag(:pensum_id, value=current_pensum.id) %>
              <%= hidden_field_tag(:course_id, value=course.id) %>
              <div class="form-inline">
                <%= check_box_tag "type[]", "other_area", course_pensum.other_area, 
                    :onclick => "$('#edit_courses_pensum_#{course_pensum.id}').submit()",
                    disabled: (current_user.role?('student') ? true : false ) %>
                <%= label_tag 'OA', nil, class: "checkbox" %>
<% end %>
```

Thank you all!